# Json-rpc 2.0 - How to extract data

Tags: python, json, json-rpc

I am trying to extract data from an in-house project(http:\192.168.1.15:8082). It uses `json-rpc 2.0`. At first, I tried using beautilsoup to retrieve the information since it was being displayed on the screen, but that does not work, all I get is a bunch o function code. I am not familiar with json-rpc.  Any help is welcome.

The REPONSE data printed on the website look like this:

RESPONSE:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"uri":"Geometry","time":1537525006,"geo":{"type":"characteristic","id":125,"information2":{"type":"Point","Weight":[15.362154,196.623546]}
```

How do I retrieve this information?

Thank you all,

Nick,

Comment: What do you mean by extract data? Is there an API to query? if so try using `requests` - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `requests` https://pypi.org/project/requests

To obey the standard you need to put in the `payload` to your request but otherwise it is just a normal `post`

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    url = "http://192.168.1.15:8082/jsonrpc"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    # Example echo method
    payload = {
        "method": "your_method_name",
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 0,
    }
    response = requests.post(
        url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()

    print(response)
    print(response['result']['uri'])
    print(response['result']['time'])
    print(response['result']['geo'])
    print(response['result']['geo']['id'])
    print(response['result']['geo']['type'])
    print(response['result']['geo']['information2'])
    print(response['result']['geo']['information2']['type'])
    print(response['result']['geo']['information2']['Weight'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want something that is specifically json_rpc then take a look at `jsonrpc_requests` https://pypi.org/project/jsonrpc-requests/
Notice in this one how the deserialization of the response is handled for you and you just get back the result of the method call rather than the whole response.

```
from jsonrpc_requests import Server

def main():
    url = "http://localhost:8082/jsonrpc"
    server = Server(url)
    result  = server.dosomething()


    print(result)
    print(result['uri'])
    print(result['time'])
    print(result['geo'])
    print(result['geo']['id'])
    print(result['geo']['type'])
    print(result['geo']['information2'])
    print(result['geo']['information2']['type'])
    print(result['geo']['information2']['Weight'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```